# Error with variable with Gradle 8 new buildDir method

Tags: gradle

`task deployZip(dependsOn: prepareDeploy, type: Zip) { dependsOn prepareDeploy include '**/*' archiveFileName = "${rootProject.name}.zip" into layout.buildDirectory.dir("deployZip") from layout.buildDirectory.dir("deploy/${rootProject.name}") }`

The from line gives me an error.

`

> Execution failed for task ':deployZip'.
> Error while evaluating property 'rootSpec$1.destPath' of task ':deployZip'.
> Cannot convert the provided notation to a String: map(org.gradle.api.file.Directory property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, ........../build)) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$PathToDirectoryTransformer@15182430).
> The following types/formats are supported:
> - String or CharSequence instances, for example "some/path".
> - Boolean values, for example true, Boolean.TRUE.
> - Number values, for example 42, 3.14.
> - A File instance
> - A Closure that returns any supported value.
> - A Callable that returns any supported value.
> - A Provider that provides any supported value.
> `

To use new Gradle 8